# greater integer width

Tags: c

i m trying to enter a five digit number greater than 32767 and i used "unsigned" while declaring int number, and when i m trying to print the same number it prints some arbitary negative number,
results get overflowed......
pls help me out

Comment: Show some of the actual code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried providing the int with bigger pants?

Comment: Use correct format specifier. Using incorrect format specifier in print() may cause UB.

Comment: If you are using a 32 or 64 bit platform, I suggest that you don't use a 16 bit compiler which is probably an antique at that.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I am guessing you are using %d or %i in the printf statement.  Use %u instead.

Answer (score 1):

Print unsigned values using "%u" instead of "%d".

Answer (score 0):

Until you show some of the code, I can't be sure of anything.

But AFAIK you shouldn't be able to print out a negative number if you're printing out an `uint` – even if it overflows, the integer will always hold a positive number, as far as C is concerned.

So there's something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct format specifier.

%d for int
%u for unsigned int.

Using incorrect format specifier in printf() may cause **Undefined Behavior**.

For example, the following code invokes *Undefined Behavior(UB)*.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int z=Some_value; /*Some_value is an unsigned int */
    printf("%d",z); 
  /*UB as format specifier for unsigned int is incorrect,it should be %u not %d*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess int is 16bit on your machine/compiler.

Though I don't know what your platform is, I guess that **long** would solve your problem (it is 32bit or more on all platforms I know). Print it with **%ld** instead of %d.

Don't get tempted to use unsigned and %u, because they will just give you numbers up to 65536, and I guess that you want more.